# How to create a limited number of pre-configured DropDownList and Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to create in a repeater a DropDownList and a TextBox for simulating a typical question list

My question is, how can I create 5 rows in my repeater with this dropdownlists and textboxes

Q: DropDownList1
A: TextBox1

Q: DropDownList2
A: TextBox2

Q: DropDownList3
A: TextBox3

Q: DropDownList4
A: TextBox4

Q: DropDownList5
A: TextBox5

Another day we could change the number of questions to 3, so my repeater should bind 3 Q-A

How can I do this dynamically.

I create the structure like this... but I don't know how to begin the Load event in order to render as I said before.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuestion" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way might be to encapsulate those low-order controls in a higher order control (namely an ASCX) and then add that to the placeholder in a loop. This way you get the benefit of being able to easily change the ASCX without repercussions on the outer looping code.

Edit: "adding" means creating the controls and then attaching them as children.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. That's what I wanted. A loop and a placeholder would be enough!

Comment: Remember to correctly assign IDs to the generated controls or you'll have a hard time retrieving data on post-back: string.Format("MyControl_InstanceID_{0}", i);